# arranging dynamic list in jsp page in the specified structure using table

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i have a list which is dynamically generated.and i want this list should be displayed using table. the structure should be as follows

suppose if i have 6 values, the first 3 values should be in first row and second 3 should be in second row
how can i do it dynamically

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the above tr structure should repeat for every 3 elements

i tried doing with divs.its working but i want the same to be implemented using table.
help me out.

regards,
ravi.

what i mean to say is the list is a collection of beans.in each bean i had some values.so my table looks like as follows

this is the list am iterating

```
<c:forEach value="#{theList}" var="item">

<div class="customer">
<p>${item.field1}</p>
<p>${item.field1}</p>
</div>

</c:foreach>
```

from above the div customer should be in the structure as follows

- the first 3 beans should be in first row with 3 columns
- the second 3 beans should be in second row with 3 columns
- continues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSTL:

```html
<table>
    <c:forEach items="#{theList}" var="item" varStatus="i">
    <c:if test="${i.index % 3 == 0 or i.begin}">
    <tr>
    </c:if>
        <td>${item.field}</td>
    <c:if test="${i.index % 3 == 0 or i.last}">
    </tr>
    </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I understood that you want to print a table every 3 times (done), then you want to print the first 3 fields in the 1st row (done) and the next 3 fields in the 2nd row (done). At the end, I use the same test to check if the table should be closed or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${loopableObject}" var="theObject" varStatus="theCount">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <c:if test='${(status.index) lt 3}'>

    <td>${item.field1}</td>
    <td>${item.field2}</td>
    <td>${item.field3}</td>

   </c:if>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <c:if test='${(status.index) gt 2}'>
    <td>${item.field1}</td>
    <td>${item.field2}</td>
    <td>${item.field3}</td>

   </c:if>
</tr>
</table>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: `lt` means *less than*, and modulus of 2 is always 0 or 1.

Comment: I guess that OP is who decides what answer's the better

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza see the updated question i dont want the table should come. for every tr tag 3 td's should be there and tr should decide based on size of list.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested it, something like this might work.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${yourList}" varStatus="loopStatus">
            <c:if test="${loopStatus.index % 3 == 0 }"><tr></c:if>
                <td><c:out value="${item}"/></td>
            <c:if test="${loopStatus.index % 3 == 0 }"></tr></c:if> 
        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${yourList.size % 3 != 0 }"></tr></c:if>
</table>
```