# How to iterate data horizontally in jstl

Tags: html, loops, jstl

I want to iterate over 10 rows of data in a table but horizontally.

```
<table>
 <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
  <tr>
    <td>${i}</td> <td>${i}</td> <td>${i}</td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This code displays data like this:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
...
```

but I want to iterate over it like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

How to do this ? Please help me out from this. I am stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you finding hard? How to format a table in HTML or working out when to move to the next line?

Comment: I just want to list data horizontally, like 1 2 3 at first row and 4 5 6 at next row and 7 8 9 at next row... please help me

Comment: Use the following to work out when to move to the next line:  <c:if test="${(i mod 3) == 0}">

Comment: it is not working as I expected, complete answer please.

Comment: I'm trying to get you to help yourself. It really is pretty simple now I've given you this. Why don't you post the code you now have that's not working?

Comment: I tried like this: 
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
         <c:if test="${(i mod 3) == 0}">
      <tr>
        <td>${i}</td>
        <td>${i+1}</td>
        <td>${i+2}</td>
      </tr>
      </c:if>
     </c:forEach>

Comment: possible duplicate of [arranging dynamic list in jsp page in the specified structure using table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137942/arranging-dynamic-list-in-jsp-page-in-the-specified-structure-using-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not near a computer to check, but it's going to be something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10"> 
            <td>${i}</td>
            <c:if test="${(i mod 3) == 0}"> <%-- New row if 3rd column --%>
                </tr><tr>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, but it's "something like" the answer. I felt forced into posting ;-)

Comment: @Margin it great, the output is same what I want but in jsp page is not properly parsed displaying information like "No end tag (</c:forEach>)"

Comment: @NarayanSubedi No it doesn't. Please refer to the possible duplicate link and the provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is, iterate through first 9 values and then put the last data in last row

```
<table>
 <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" step="3" end="9">
  <tr>
    <td>${i}</td> <td>${i}</td> <td>${i}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>${10}</td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: This approach is still too much hard coded. If you want to use steps of 4 you have to manually add a fourth `<td>` structure and its contents.